# Python conventions - using variables and substitution

Tags: python

Am reading the first chapter of http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Introduction/introduction.html#review-of-basic-python. Why is:

```
print("%s is %d years old." % (aName, age))
```

(aka using **formatted strings**) preferred as the convention over just using variables directly in the sentence, i.e.:

```
print(aName, "is", age, "years old.")
```

?

Comment: `str.format` is the preferred method now.  There is nothing wrong with using commas to join strings, you may get undesirable spaces and you can't format things such as numbers and padding.

Comment: If you keep reading, the tutorial goes over the more advanced control format strings give you. You don't need it here, and I don't think the tutorial says to prefer it when you don't need it. It's kind of weird that they use old-style string formatting and keep calling the strings "formatted strings" instead of "format strings", though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good habit to get into using the formatted string versions.

Often they are clearer to read, but most importantly to me, it makes [internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) possible.

Even better, use the keyword/mapping versions. eg.

```
print "{name} is {age} years old.".format(name=aName, age=age)
```

Automated tools can have a better chance of scanning your program for these strings to create the ".po" files needed for translation.

I usually just use the comma version if I'm doing something quick and just want to print a bunch of numbers or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned str.format is now the recommended way.  From my personal experience an example of '%s'%(str) being buggy is with sql statements...

```
q = "select * from table where colName like '%string%' and colName2 = %s"
conn.cursor.execute(q%'screwsUp')
```

The Above doesn't work
But Below does

```
q = "select * from table where colName like '%string%' and colName2 = {0}" 
conn.cursor.execute(q.format('works'))
```

format is also way sexier when you want to insert dictionary values...

```
d = {"first":"ronald","last":"McDonald"}
print "Name's {0[last]}... {0[first]} {0[last]}".format(d)
```